Solve $\sqrt{1-x}=2x^2-1+2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Find x in the irrational equation below:
$$\sqrt{1-x}=2x^2-1+2x\sqrt{1-x^2}$$
Answer: $x = \cos 54^\circ$

I try:
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{1-x} &=2x^2-1+2x\sqrt{1-x^2} \tag1 \\
\sqrt{1-x} &=2x^2-1+2x\sqrt{(1-x)(1+x)} \tag2 \\
\sqrt{1-x}-2x\sqrt{(1-x)(1+x)} &=2x^2-1 \tag3 \\
1-x-4x(\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{(1-x)(1+x)}+4x^2(1-x^2)&=4x^4-4x^2+1 \tag4 \\
4x^4-4x^2+4x(1-x)\sqrt{(1+x)}-4x^2+4x^4 &=0 \tag5 \\
8x^4-8x^2+4x(1-x)\sqrt{(1+x)} &=0 \tag6 \\
2x^4-2x^2+(1-x)\sqrt{(1-x)} &=0 \tag7 \\
&\text{???}
\end{align}$$

Also check this.

@Etemon Thanks for help
